# Search UISearchDisplayController w/ Scope Only

Tags: iphone

I am using UISearchDisplayController to pull in results from a webservice but I want to be able to search even if the search bar's text is empty. It seems like results are only being pulled in if this is not empty. How do I update & show the results tableview by only scope?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can put the condition when the scope button is changed

```
if([searchBar.text length])
{
  //CALL FOR QUERY ACCORDING TO TEXT IN SEARCHBOX
}
else
{
  //CALL THE QUERY AS PER CHANGE IN SCOPE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the - (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate to search and then reload the searchResultsTableView (UISearchDisplayController)

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't that I can initiate the search, it's that the resultsTableView will not display unless you have something entered in the UISearchBar.